# What is the etymology of ypologistís (Greek, computer)?

Tags: etymology, greek

Is **ypologistís** (Greek for computer) derived from, or related to,

> apologeisthai "to speak in one's defense," from apologos "an account,
>   story," 
>   ([Etomonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=a&p=36&allowed_in_frame=0))

I have now been informed by Janus Bahs Jacquet that the Ancient Greek word was **hypologistēs**.  A bit of searching gave me the meaning of logistes:

> auditor or accountant who scrutinizes the accounts of other officials
>   who have authority over public funds

Source: [Nature, Justice, and Rights in Aristotle's Politics
By Fred Dycus Miller](https://books.google.com/books?id=6iQSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=logist%C4%93s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW5L7AzrrOAhUlL8AKHYTlDKQQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=logist%C4%93s&f=false)

But what was the **hypologistes**?  An underling of the logistes, a clerk?

And does it derive from logike and ultimately from logos?  [Etomonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=l&p=26&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: hypologistēs does not seem to be an Ancient Greek word -- at least it is not in the Liddell-Scott dictionary: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=upologisths&lang=greek

Comment: Seems unlikely, since *ἀπό-* and *ὑπό-* are distinct in Greek...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Modern Greek word was formed from Classical ὑπολογίζομαι "to take something into account", which of course comes from λόγος.

http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.77:4:77.LSJ

Answer (score 0):

In Russian,

> счёт = counting, account
>
> подсчёт = (under + counting) calculation, final summation

I think it is natural that final calculation has the "under-" prefix because when you sum up things, you write the result under the summed up data.

Comment: That is an interesting observation. ὑπολογίζομαι  does not actually mean "calculate", but it can mean "subtract" .... sub + trahere.